# Operating NI USRP-2920 by GNURadio

Tags: gnuradio, usrp

I try to operate NI USRP-2920 by GNUradio.
At the first, I typed "uhd_find_devices".
Result is below.

```
----------------------------------------------
-- UHD Devices 0
----------------------------------------------
Device Address:
   serial: 3077BE9
   adde: 192.168.10.4
   name:
   type: usrp2
```

In the next, I typed "uhd_usrp_probe" in terminal.
Result is below.

> Error: RuntimeError:  Please update the firmware and FPGA images for
>   your device. See the application notes for USRP2/N-Series for
>   instructions. Expected FPGA compatibility number 11, but got 10: The
>   FPGA build is not compatible with the host code build. Please run:
>
> "/usr/local/lib/uhd/utils/uhd_images_downloader.py" 
>   "/usr/local/bin/uhd_image_loader" \
>       --args="type=usrp2,addr=192.168.10.4"

Therefore, I runned uhd_images_downloader. But, I typed
"uhd_usrp_probe" is the same result(RuntimError:update the firmware).

Could you tell me any advices?
Thank you.

Comment: execute as sudo

Comment: Did you also run the uhd_image_loader after the uhd_image_downloader

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
I typed "uhd_image_downloder" after renewing ubuntu.
As a result, I could connect USRP.
Thank you for advice.